# Update asp.net core Authentication outside of Startup.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

With respect to asp.net core identity management, we have a requirement to change the Microsoft ClientId and ClientSecret after our asp.net core app has started and, therefore, not in startup.cs.  We have various identity management logins working fine with, for example this for Microsoft Azure:

```
            .AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
            {
                microsoftOptions.CorrelationCookie.HttpOnly = true;
                microsoftOptions.CorrelationCookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                microsoftOptions.ClientId = "removed";
                microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = "removed";
            })
```

We now need to change the ClientId and ClientSecret dynamically after the core application has started and what we can't figure out is how to access this from the services collection later in other pages so we can update them.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core provides `IAuthenticationSchemeProvider` interface to dynamically add/remove authentication schemes at runtime. You can inject this interface and add *Microsoft Account* auth schemes after the app has started.

Using [Microsoft's demo app](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/0c5456afe95096db6ac5400cecd3440299b42714/src/Security/samples/DynamicSchemes/Controllers/AuthController.cs) as reference, here's a basic implementation:

```cs
public class DynamicAuthController: ControllerBase
{
    private IAuthenticationSchemeProvider _schemeProvider;
    private IOptionsMonitorCache<MicrosoftAccountOptions> _optionsCache;

    public DynamicAuthController(IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemeProvider, IOptionsMonitorCache<MicrosoftAccountOptions> optionsCache)
    {
        _schemeProvider = schemeProvider;
        _optionsCache = optionsCache;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        var schemeName = "MicrosoftCustom1"; // must be unique for different schemes
        var schemeOptions = new MicrosoftAccountOptions
        {
            ClientId = "ididid", // fetch credentials from another service or database
            ClientSecret = "secretsecret",
            CorrelationCookie =
            {
                HttpOnly = true,
                SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always
            }
        };
        
        var scheme = new AuthenticationScheme(schemeName, displayName:null, typeof(MicrosoftAccountHandler));
        _schemeProvider.TryAddScheme(scheme);
        _optionsCache.TryAdd(
            schemeName,
            schemeOptions
        );

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - will explore that approach.

Shame we can't just update the ClientId and ClientSecret in here


            var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
            ChallengeResult cr = new ChallengeResult(provider, properties);

Comment: You might be able to hack it together by subclassing `MicrosoftAccountHandler` and keeping credentials in `AuthenticationProperties.Items` and reading it inside `MicrosoftAccountHandler.BuildChallengeUrl` and `.ExchangeCodeAsync` but I would lean towards this approach.