# How to inject services in an AddOpenIdConnect event (OnTokenValidated)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, duende-identity-server

I need to write and business logic which requires `ConfigureServices` to get fully executed.
`OnTokenValidated` is badly located with-in `ConfigureServices` itself.

> What is the alternative of `AddOpenIdConnect` middleware so that I can
> `Success` call with full flexibility to use injected services?

```
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "cookie";
            //...
        })
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";
            /....
            options.Scope.Add("offline_access");

            options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async n =>
            {
                //Need other services which will only 
                //get injected once ConfigureServices method has fully executed.
            };
        }
```

**Reference: Why**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0#ASP0000

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68510106/5298150

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To resolve services inside the `OnTokenValidated` event handler, you can use `TokenValidatedContext.HttpContext.RequestServices`:

```cs
Events =
{
    OnTokenValidated = async context =>
    {
        var someService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ISomeService>();
        var result = await someService.DoSomethingAsync();
        // a custom callback
    }
}
```