# How to use DI in a class referenced in Program.cs that must be static

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

First off, sorry for the really bad question title. I couldn't think of a better way to word it. I'm open to suggestions for an edit!

In my ASP.NET app written to target .NET 7, I have this in my Program.cs class:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.Configure<AppConfiguration>(builder.Configuration.GetSection(AppConfiguration.ConfigurationSectionName));

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}
)
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    options.ClientId = "whatever";
    // etc...

    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
    {
        OnRemoteFailure = AuthenticationHelper.OnAuthenticationFailed,
        OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = AuthenticationHelper.OnAuthenticationSucceeded
    };
});
```

Then I have my AuthenticationHelper class which, at the moment (I need to build it out) looks like this:

```
internal static class AuthenticationHelper
{
    internal static Task OnAuthenticationFailed(RemoteFailureContext context)
    {
        context.HandleResponse();
        context.Response.Redirect("/?errormessage=" + context.Failure?.Message ?? string.Empty);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    internal static Task OnAuthenticationSucceeded(AuthorizationCodeReceivedContext context)
    {
        var claim = new Claim(_appConfiguration.MyClaimName, "My value");
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Note that second-to-last line, where I'm referencing a variable named `_appConfiguration`. That obviously doesn't work because the variable isn't declared anywhere. I've copied this line from another class where dependency injection is used to inject the app configuration.

The problem is that I obviously can't use DI in my AuthenticationHelper class becaues it's a `static` class, and, so far, I can't work out how to change it to a standard class (i.e. not `static`) and still be able to reference it when assigning values to `OnRemoteFailure` and `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` in Program.cs.

As far as I can see, my two options are to either:

1. Find another way to get the app configuration in Authentication Helper without using DI.
2. Find a way to reference an instance of AuthenticationHelper in Program.cs if I make it non-static.

So far, I can't figure out how to do either! The closest I've come is to make the AuthenticationHelper class non-static, add it as a singleton service in Program.cs, and change the event option assignments to e.g.:

```
OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IAuthenticationHelper>().OnAuthenticationSucceeded
```

This works, but I'm aware that using `BuildServiceProvider()` is a bad idea, as it creates a new instance of the singleon class every time.

What's the best approach to this?

Comment: The simple answer is: make `AuthenticationHelper` non-static, and inject it as a singleton instance.

Comment: I tried that, but like I said, I couldn't then work out how to assign its methods to the `OnRemoteFailure` and `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` variables.

Comment: Ah. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68548354/2791540)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52325438/how-to-inject-dependency-to-static-class

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66264937/264697

Comment: @JohnWu I actually prefer that answer over the others here, but I'm not sure what the protocol is on accepting an answer. Do you want to post an answer with the link that I can accept, or should I add an anaswer and cite it myself?

Answer (score 2):

If `AuthenticationHelper` needs to be static, [Method Injection](https://freecontent.manning.com/understanding-method-injection/) is the generally the answer.

This means that, in your case, you add `AppConfiguration` as parameter to the `OnAuthenticationSucceeded` method, as shown here:

```cs
internal static class AuthenticationHelper
{
    ...

    internal static Task OnAuthenticationSucceeded(
        AuthorizationCodeReceivedContext context,
        AppConfiguration appConfiguration) // <-- Apply Method Injection here
    {
        var claim = new Claim(appConfiguration.MyClaimName, "My value");
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Inside your Composition Root you then supply `AppConfiguration` to the `OnAuthenticationSucceeded` method, as demonstrated next:

```cs
var appSection = builder.Configuration
    .GetSection(AppConfiguration.ConfigurationSectionName);
var appConfig = appSection.Get<AppConfiguration>();
builder.Services.Configure<AppConfiguration>(appSection);

...

.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    options.ClientId = "whatever";
    // etc...

    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
    {
        OnRemoteFailure = AuthenticationHelper.OnAuthenticationFailed,
        OnAuthorizationCodeReceived =
            context => AuthenticationHelper.OnAuthenticationSucceeded(
                context,
                appConfig) // <-- Method Injection here
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Register `AppConfiguration` as DI service and access it using the context object like this:

```cs
internal static Task OnAuthenticationSucceeded(AuthorizationCodeReceivedContext context)
{
    var appConfiguration = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<AppConfiguration>();

    var claim = new Claim(appConfiguration.MyClaimName, "My value");
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```